# contrapositive prove if n and m are even integers then n-m are even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I solved it

n is odd and m is odd then n-m is odd

n= 2k+1

m=2b+1

---

(2k+1)-(2b+1)

2k+1-2b-1

2k-2b

2(k-b)

2r

How can this be may even. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: The contrapositive is wrong.

Comment: n-m is odd, then n or m is odd.

Comment: $(P\wedge Q)\to R$ is equivalent via contraposition to $\neg R\to \neg(P\wedge Q)$ or rewritten $\neg R\to (\neg P\vee \neg Q)$.  That is to say, if you wanted to prove this via contrapositive you should have shown that if $n-m$  is odd then $n$ is odd or $m$ is odd.  You attempted to show the *Converse* (*but still made a mistake by not changing 'and' to 'or'*) which is not logically equivalent to the original.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to prove this directly. If $n$ and $m$ are even, then $n = 2r$ and $m = 2s$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$n - m = 2r - 2s = 2(r - s),$$
so $n-m$ is even.

If you insist on proving the contrapositive: if $n-m$ is odd, then $n-m = 2k + 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $n = 2k + m + 1$. If $m$ were even, then $m = 2t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, so
$$n = 2k + 2t + 1 = 2(k+t) + 1,$$
so $n$ is odd, so not both $n$ and $m$ are even. If $m$ were odd, the proof is complete already because not both $n$ and $m$ are even.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the form of a contrapositive; you want to prove something like
$$(P\land Q)\implies V,$$
the contrapositive of that is $\neg V\implies(\neg P\lor\neg Q )$.

With this you can now make a good contrapositive.

> Now, with the contrapositive, you have to prove that (n-m) is odd, then n is odd or m is odd